# How to delete ROOT APPS from Andoid jelly beans?

Tags: system-apps

I am using Galaxy s3 dous, Whenever I turn on my wifi my phone itself start downloading google apps, and I am unable to uninstall them, In application manager there is no option to remove but to update only. And same in playstore>>My Apps. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible on stock ROMs. And it's not possible on other ROMs either when you want Google Apps. As long as Google Apps are installed (and a network connection is available), they will update automatically.